# PerformanceWarning: DataFrame is highly fragmented when creating new DataFrame columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, warnings

I am trying to set new DataFrame columns as simple calculation of existing DataFrame, but when I run the script I get the warning from Pandas.
Here is the main code

```
data_join['Ele_total'] = data_ele.sum(axis=1)
data_join['PV_total'] = data_pv.sum(axis=1)
data_join['SC'] = np.where(data_join['PV_total']>data_join['Ele_total'], data_join['Ele_total'], data_join['PV_total'])
data_join['SC%'] = np.where(data_join['PV_total']!= 0,round((data_join['SC']/data_join['PV_total'])*100,0),0)
data_join['SS%'] = np.where(data_join['Ele_total']!= 0,round((data_join['SC']/data_join['Ele_total'])*100,0),0)
data_join['LOLP'] = data_join['Ele_total']>data_join['PV_total']
data_join['E_tg'] = data_join['PV_total']-data_join['SC']
data_join['E_fg'] = data_join['Ele_total']-data_join['SC']
data_join['Ei'] = data_join['E_tg']-data_join['E_fg']
data_join['NGIP'] = data_join['Ei'].abs()<(GRID_LIM*n_build)
data_join['PAL'] = data_join['Ei'].abs()>(PEAK_LIM*n_build)
data_join['CO2'] = data_CO2['GWP']
data_join['CO2_net'] = data_CO2['GWP']*data_join['SC']
data_join['CO2_tot'] = data_CO2['GWP']*(data_join['E_tg']+data_join['SC'])



cash_flow = 0
npv = []
data_join_npv = pd.DataFrame()

for i in range (0,25):
    if i == 0:
        data_join_npv['PV_total_res_{}'.format(i)] = data_join_res['PV_total']
        data_join_npv['PV_total_ind_{}'.format(i)] = data_join_ind['PV_total']
    else:
        data_join_npv['PV_total_res_{}'.format(i)] = data_join_npv['PV_total_res_{}'.format(i-1)]*(1-d)
        data_join_npv['PV_total_ind_{}'.format(i)] = data_join_npv['PV_total_ind_{}'.format(i-1)]*(1-d)
    
    data_join_npv['SC_res_{}'.format(i)] = np.where(data_join_npv['PV_total_res_{}'.format(i)]>data_join_res['Ele_total'], data_join_res['Ele_total'], data_join_npv['PV_total_res_{}'.format(i)])
    data_join_npv['SC_ind_{}'.format(i)] = np.where(data_join_npv['PV_total_ind_{}'.format(i)]>data_join_ind['Ele_total'], data_join_ind['Ele_total'], data_join_npv['PV_total_ind_{}'.format(i)])
    data_join_npv['E_tg_res_{}'.format(i)] = data_join_npv['PV_total_res_{}'.format(i)]-data_join_npv['SC_res_{}'.format(i)]
    data_join_npv['E_tg_ind_{}'.format(i)] = data_join_npv['PV_total_ind_{}'.format(i)]-data_join_npv['SC_ind_{}'.format(i)]
    data_join_npv['E_fg_res_{}'.format(i)] = data_join_res['Ele_total']-data_join_npv['SC_res_{}'.format(i)]
    data_join_npv['E_fg_ind_{}'.format(i)] = data_join_ind['Ele_total']-data_join_npv['SC_ind_{}'.format(i)]
    cash = float(data_join_npv['SC_res_{}'.format(i)].sum())*COST_OF_ENERGY_RES + float(data_join_npv['E_tg_res_{}'.format(i)].sum())*VALUE_OF_ENERGY - float(data_join_npv['E_fg_res_{}'.format(i)].sum())*COST_OF_ENERGY_RES + float(data_join_npv['SC_ind_{}'.format(i)].sum())*COST_OF_ENERGY_IND + float(data_join_npv['E_tg_ind_{}'.format(i)].sum())*VALUE_OF_ENERGY - float(data_join_npv['E_fg_ind_{}'.format(i)].sum())*COST_OF_ENERGY_IND - OM_COST*total_pv
    cash_flow += cash/((1+DISC_RATE)**(i+1))
    npv.append(-in_inv+cash_flow)
```

These are the warnings that I get:

```
C:\Users\Giacomo\Desktop\150\insert_data.py:342: PerformanceWarning: DataFrame is highly fragmented.  This is usually the result of calling `frame.insert` many times, which has poor performance.  Consider joining all columns at once using pd.concat(axis=1) instead. To get a de-fragmented frame, use `newframe = frame.copy()`
  data_join_npv['E_tg_res_{}'.format(i)] = data_join_npv['PV_total_res_{}'.format(i)]-data_join_npv['SC_res_{}'.format(i)]
C:\Users\Giacomo\Desktop\150\insert_data.py:343: PerformanceWarning: DataFrame is highly fragmented.  This is usually the result of calling `frame.insert` many times, which has poor performance.  Consider joining all columns at once using pd.concat(axis=1) instead. To get a de-fragmented frame, use `newframe = frame.copy()`
  data_join_npv['E_tg_ind_{}'.format(i)] = data_join_npv['PV_total_ind_{}'.format(i)]-data_join_npv['SC_ind_{}'.format(i)]
C:\Users\Giacomo\Desktop\150\insert_data.py:344: PerformanceWarning: DataFrame is highly fragmented.  This is usually the result of calling `frame.insert` many times, which has poor performance.  Consider joining all columns at once using pd.concat(axis=1) instead. To get a de-fragmented frame, use `newframe = frame.copy()`
  data_join_npv['E_fg_res_{}'.format(i)] = data_join_res['Ele_total']-data_join_npv['SC_res_{}'.format(i)]
C:\Users\Giacomo\Desktop\150\insert_data.py:345: PerformanceWarning: DataFrame is highly fragmented.  This is usually the result of calling `frame.insert` many times, which has poor performance.  Consider joining all columns at once using pd.concat(axis=1) instead. To get a de-fragmented frame, use `newframe = frame.copy()`
  data_join_npv['E_fg_ind_{}'.format(i)] = data_join_ind['Ele_total']-data_join_npv['SC_ind_{}'.format(i)]
C:\Users\Giacomo\Desktop\150\insert_data.py:337: PerformanceWarning: DataFrame is highly fragmented.  This is usually the result of calling `frame.insert` many times, which has poor performance.  Consider joining all columns at once using pd.concat(axis=1) instead. To get a de-fragmented frame, use `newframe = frame.copy()`
  data_join_npv['PV_total_res_{}'.format(i)] = data_join_npv['PV_total_res_{}'.format(i-1)]*(1-d)
C:\Users\Giacomo\Desktop\150\insert_data.py:338: PerformanceWarning: DataFrame is highly fragmented.  This is usually the result of calling `frame.insert` many times, which has poor performance.  Consider joining all columns at once using pd.concat(axis=1) instead. To get a de-fragmented frame, use `newframe = frame.copy()`
  data_join_npv['PV_total_ind_{}'.format(i)] = data_join_npv['PV_total_ind_{}'.format(i-1)]*(1-d)
C:\Users\Giacomo\Desktop\150\insert_data.py:340: PerformanceWarning: DataFrame is highly fragmented.  This is usually the result of calling `frame.insert` many times, which has poor performance.  Consider joining all columns at once using pd.concat(axis=1) instead. To get a de-fragmented frame, use `newframe = frame.copy()`
  data_join_npv['SC_res_{}'.format(i)] = np.where(data_join_npv['PV_total_res_{}'.format(i)]>data_join_res['Ele_total'], data_join_res['Ele_total'], data_join_npv['PV_total_res_{}'.format(i)])
C:\Users\Giacomo\Desktop\150\insert_data.py:341: PerformanceWarning: DataFrame is highly fragmented.  This is usually the result of calling `frame.insert` many times, which has poor performance.  Consider joining all columns at once using pd.concat(axis=1) instead. To get a de-fragmented frame, use `newframe = frame.copy()`
  data_join_npv['SC_ind_{}'.format(i)] = np.where(data_join_npv['PV_total_ind_{}'.format(i)]>data_join_ind['Ele_total'], data_join_ind['Ele_total'], data_join_npv['PV_total_ind_{}'.format(i)])
C:\Users\Giacomo\Desktop\150\insert_data.py:342: PerformanceWarning: DataFrame is highly fragmented.  This is usually the result of calling `frame.insert` many times, which has poor performance.  Consider joining all columns at once using pd.concat(axis=1) instead. To get a de-fragmented frame, use `newframe = frame.copy()
```

I don't use `frame.insert()` as the warning suggests, so I don't get why I have this warning on fragmentation. I get the right results, but since I have to run the code multiple times inside an optimizer, I think the lots of warning I get are stopping the optimizer at some point during the analysis, and I would like to solve them.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting these multiple warnings because you are repeatedly **inserting** columns into your dataframe `data_join_npv` instead of **concatenating** them together after and outside the for-loop, which is much more efficient memory wise.

For instance, running this toy code:

```py
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({f"col{i}": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] for i in range(1_000)})

new_df = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(1_000):  # insert one thousand columns
    new_df[f"new_df_col{i}"] = df[f"col{i}"]+i

print(new_df)
```

You will get this output:

> PerformanceWarning: DataFrame is highly fragmented.  This is usually the result of calling `frame.insert` many times, which has poor performance.  Consider joining all columns at once using pd.concat(axis=1) instead. To get a de-fragmented frame, use `newframe = frame.copy()`
> new_df[f"new_df_col{i}"] = df[f"col{i}"]+i

```
   new_df_col0  new_df_col1  new_df_col2  ...  new_df_col997  new_df_col998  new_df_col999
0            0            1            2  ...            997            998            999
1            1            2            3  ...            998            999           1000
2            2            3            4  ...            999           1000           1001
3            3            4            5  ...           1000           1001           1002
4            4            5            6  ...           1001           1002           1003
5            5            6            7  ...           1002           1003           1004
6            6            7            8  ...           1003           1004           1005
7            7            8            9  ...           1004           1005           1006
8            8            9           10  ...           1005           1006           1007
9            9           10           11  ...           1006           1007           1008

[10 rows x 1000 columns]
```

Whereas, for instance, initializing an empty dictionary instead of a dataframe, and using Pandas [concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```py
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({f"col{i}": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] for i in range(1_000)})

data = {}
for i in range(1_000):
    data[f"new_col{i}"] = df[f"col{i}"] + i

new_df = pd.concat(data.values(), axis=1, ignore_index=True)
new_df.columns = data.keys()  # since Python 3.7, order of insertion is preserved

print(new_df)
```

You will get the same dataframe without any warning:

```
   new_col0  new_col1  new_col2  new_col3  ...  new_col996  new_col997  new_col998  new_col999
0         0         1         2         3  ...         996         997         998         999
1         1         2         3         4  ...         997         998         999        1000
2         2         3         4         5  ...         998         999        1000        1001
3         3         4         5         6  ...         999        1000        1001        1002
4         4         5         6         7  ...        1000        1001        1002        1003
5         5         6         7         8  ...        1001        1002        1003        1004
6         6         7         8         9  ...        1002        1003        1004        1005
7         7         8         9        10  ...        1003        1004        1005        1006
8         8         9        10        11  ...        1004        1005        1006        1007
9         9        10        11        12  ...        1005        1006        1007        1008

[10 rows x 1000 columns]
```

So, try refactoring your code like this:

```
cash_flow = 0
npv = []
data_join_npv = {}  # instead of pd.DataFrame()
for i in range (0,25):  # code unchanged
    ...
df = pd.concat(data_join_npv.values(), axis=1, ignore_index=True)
df.columns = data_join_npv.keys()
```

Comment: OK, so I should change the code and turn the empty dataframe into an empty dictionary, where the columns name become the keys of the dictionary and where the values of each key become the values of the new columns. Everything at the end achieved via .concat() function

Comment: I get "cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'numpy.ndarray'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid" probably because in the dictionary I get as last line of each series of values "Name: Ele_total, Length: 2035, dtype: float64", that I don't know how to erase.

Comment: I can only guess here, but try converting values into Series as you concatenate them, something like this: `df = pd.concat({k: pd.Series(v) for k, v in data_join_npv.items()}, axis=1, ignore_index=False)` and delete `df.columns = data_join_npv.keys()` as it is not needed anymore. Cheers.